# Python - use different .json files and be able to do it with less code of data[attachment]

Tags: python, json

What is the most effective/less code to use `data[attach.]` .json from this code:

```
with open('slack.json') as slackAttachment:
       data = json.load(slackAttachment)

with open('slack2.json') as slackAttachment:
       data2 = json.load(slackAttachment)

with open('slack3.json') as slackAttachment:
       data3 = json.load(slackAttachment)

with open('slack4.json') as slackAttachment:
       data4 = json.load(slackAttachment)


data["attachments"][0]["title"] = country  

itemname = item.get('Title', {})
if itemname: 
    newitemword = item['seoTitle']
    data["attachments"][0]["text"] = "" + newitemword + ""

else:

    data["attachments"][0]["fields"].append({
    "value": '*Item name not found*',
    "short": True,
})
```

Also there is not just these two data["attachments"][0] but around xx of them.

Basically what I DON'T want to do is:

```
 data["attachments"][0]["text"] = "" + newitemword + ""
 data2["attachments"][0]["text"] = "" + newitemword + ""
 data3["attachments"][0]["text"] = "" + newitemword + ""
 data4["attachments"][0]["text"] = "" + newitemword + ""
```

and I wonder if there is maybe other effective way to solve it with less code than the code above and still be able to use all these slacks.json for their own?

EDIT:

```
webhook0 = 'HELLO'
webhook1 = 'WORLD
webhook2 = 'STACK'


       data = {}


                    file_numbers = range(0, 3)  # I assume the numbers are from 1 to 4, but you can change this.
                    for file_number in file_numbers:  # go overf file numbers
                        file_name = 'slack' + str(file_number) + '.json'  # create file name from number
                        with open(file_name) as slackAttachment:
                            data[file_number] = (json.load(slackAttachment))  # append file json to data list
                        webhook_number = 'webhook' + str(file_number)

                    print(webhook_number)

                    # data is now complete
                    # you can use data[file_number] to access the corresponding json

                    for file_number in file_numbers:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all your data into a single `dict`.

```
data = {}

file_numbers = range(1, 5) # I assume the numbers are from 1 to 4, but you can change this.
for file_number in file_numbers: # go overf file numbers
    file_name = 'slack' + str(file_number) + '.json' # create file name from number

    with open(file_name) as slackAttachment:
        data[file_number] = (json.load(slackAttachment)) # append file json to data list

# data is now complete
# you can use data[file_number] to access the corresponding json

for file_number in file_numbers:

    data[file_number]["attachments"][0]["title"] = country

    itemname = item.get('Title', {})
    if itemname:
        newitemword = item['seoTitle']
        data[file_number]["attachments"][0]["text"] = "" + newitemword + ""

    else:

        data[file_number]["attachments"][0]["fields"].append({
            "value": '*Item name not found*',
            "short": True,
        })
```

every time you want to access the data of a file, you use `data[<file_number>]`.

So to access the first `slack.json` you use `data[0]`

Comment: Is it possible to add this into a method etc def slack(): ? Somehow, I tried to figure out but no luck!

Comment: Also it says `range() does not take keyword arguments`

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.6 :)

Comment: Also I forgot to mention there is also at the end 
```response = s.post(webhook, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})``` How do I change the data in that case to send each requests specific?

Comment: I edtied the range, shoud work now. Everywhere that you have `data`, use `data[file number]` instead. So, `response = s.post(webhook, data=json.dumps(data[file number]), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})`

Comment: Oh okey! Im gonna give it a try :)

Comment: Seems to work! However its the same issue again where I have now 3 different webhook at the top etc webhook0=hello webhook1=world webhook2=stackoverflow and all of them has their own value. How would I n that case be able to print out each of these value. I did ``` webhook_number = 'webhook' + str(file_number)``` but that just prinited out webhook0 - 1 - 2 but not the actually value in them

Comment: `webhooks = {1: 'hello', 2: 'world', 3:'stackoverflow'}; for file_number in file_numbers: print(webhooks[file_number])`